# Qt widget based on QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I try to create my own widget based in QWidget. In constructor of the class i have:

```
Square(QWidget *parent = 0, const char *name = 0, WFlags fl = 0);

Square::Square(QWidget *parent = 0, const char *name = 0, WFlags fl)
        : QWidget(parent, name, f)
{
        if (!name)
                setName("Game");
        reset();
        underMouse=false;
}
```

But i see error: **‘WFlags’ has not been declared**

Now i remade my code:

```
class Square : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Square(QWidget *parent = 0);
};
```

and in square.cpp:

```
Square::Square(QWidget *parent)
        : QWidget(parent)
{
}
```

But i see error:

- error: undefined reference to `vtable for Square'
- error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  What's wrong? How can i declare constructor of the class based in QWidget?

Thank you.

Comment: It's probably a typo, but your parameter name is `fl` and the name you pass to the QWidget constructor is `f`.

Comment: Re-run qmake and see if the vtable error goes away.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555816/qt-object-linker-problem-undefined-reverence-to-vtable

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Qt4, the compiler is absolutely right.  `WFlags` has not been declared.  It's `Qt::WindowFlags`.  Also, you don't need `name` -- that's a Qt3 thing.

See http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qwidget.html#QWidget

By the way, I never bother to allow passing `WindowFlags` through my constructors.  If you look at the standard Qt widgets, they don't either (e.g. http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qpushbutton.html#QPushButton).