# Qt undefined reference to vtable

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt4, codeblocks

I am a beginner to Qt programming and use codeblocks for my programming. I created 3 files communicate.h,commmunicate.cpp and main.cpp as follows:

**communicate.h**

```
    #ifndef COMMUNICATE_H
    #define COMMUNICATE_H

    #include <QWidget>
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QPushButton>
    #include <QLabel>

    class Communicate : public QWidget
    {
      Q_OBJECT

      public:
        Communicate(QWidget *parent = 0);


      private slots:
        void OnPlus();
        void OnMinus();

      private:
        QLabel *label;

    };

    #endif
```

**communicate.cpp**

```
#include "communicate.h"

Communicate::Communicate(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
  QPushButton *plus = new QPushButton("+", this);
  plus->setGeometry(50, 40, 75, 30);

  QPushButton *minus = new QPushButton("-", this);
  minus->setGeometry(50, 100, 75, 30);

  label = new QLabel("0", this);
  label->setGeometry(190, 80, 20, 30);

  connect(plus, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(OnPlus()));
  connect(minus, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(OnMinus()));
}

void Communicate::OnPlus()
{
  int val = label->text().toInt();
  val++;
  label->setText(QString::number(val));
}

void Communicate::OnMinus()
{
  int val = label->text().toInt();
  val--;
  label->setText(QString::number(val));
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "communicate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  Communicate window;

  window.setWindowTitle("Communicate");
  window.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

and its showing errors as follows:

```
obj\Debug\main.o(.text$_ZN11CommunicateD1Ev[Communicate::~Communicate()]+0xb)||In function `ZN7QStringC1EPKc':|
C:\Qt\4.4.3\include\QtCore\..\..\src\corelib\arch\qatomic_windows.h||undefined reference to `vtable for Communicate'|
obj\Debug\main.o(.text$_ZN11CommunicateD1Ev[Communicate::~Communicate()]+0x17):C:\Qt\4.4.3\include\QtCore\..\..\src\corelib\arch\qatomic_windows.h||undefined reference to `vtable for Communicate'|
obj\Debug\communicate.o(.text+0x172)||In function `ZN11CommunicateC2EP7QWidget':|
E:\Project\cam2\communicate.cpp|5|undefined reference to `vtable for Communicate'|
obj\Debug\communicate.o(.text+0x17e):E:\Project\cam2\communicate.cpp|5|undefined reference to `vtable for Communicate'|
obj\Debug\communicate.o(.text+0x63a)||In function `ZN11CommunicateC1EP7QWidget':|
E:\Project\cam2\communicate.cpp|5|undefined reference to `vtable for Communicate'|
obj\Debug\communicate.o(.text+0x646):E:\Project\cam2\communicate.cpp|5|more undefined references to `vtable for Communicate' follow|
||=== Build finished: 6 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

guys please help...cant figure it out...

Comment: make sure that your project file(.pro) includes communicate.h file in headers section

Comment: This is a duplicate, not too localized

Comment: the best answer I found, and that is not mentioned here is to rerun qmake: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3650758/258418

Comment: Thanks ted, your re-run qmake comment is what fixed it for me. Not sure when or how the problem was triggered, but what eventually fixed it was manually deleting the Makefile file, triggering it's regeneration within Qt Creator.

Comment: @Jijo Jose and to everyone: I am not sure if something goes wrong with my system, but for me **deleting the build directory** fixed the problem. (Even "Clean all" was not enough). I guess it is because the `moc` (generated) file could not access the header. I hope this will help someone.

Comment: Zeks's reply works for me

Comment: Another reason I ran into the same problem is because, for some reason, if I didn't #include<QObject>, qmake didn't identify my code as needing to be MOCed (QObject was included from another include file).  Adding #include<QObject> fixed it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is a subtle bug (and probably partly at least a compiler bug) that I've seen before. Since QWidget has a virtual destructor, the compiler needs a vtable for your class. But your class doesn't have any virtual functions, so it didn't build one for your Communicate class.

Add a `virtual ~Communicate() {};` to your class, and all will be well.

Yes, it took me some time to figure this out too!

Comment: You are not correct. I just tested this class: class Test: public QObject {Q_OBJECT} and this compiles just fine assuming header file resides in .pro The moment I comment it out - I get the undefinde reference to vtable

Comment: Ok, I've seen this problem in a different setup, where QT wasn't involved at all, and the problem was caused by not having a destructor declared. So it may be that the MOC is "fixing" this sort of thing on the fly?

Comment: The code compiles fine if you add communicate.h in HEADERS section.

Comment: I tried adding the code u mentioned into the class under public: but stil the problem persists...........

Comment: The class does have virtual functions, they are declared by the Q_OBJECT macro. Why is this answer accepted??

Comment: Saved my life using QObject and QGraphicsItem as public with signal / slots

Comment: I was still having this issue, until I re-ran `qmake` in qtcreator's build menu.

Comment: Since I was stuck for hours on a similar problem and this comes up as first result on search engine: If you use cmake, try adding `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)` to the configuration. Cmake will not run Qt's 'meta object compiler' on your source files otherwise. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/moc.html

Answer (score 37):

MOC(meta object compiler) needs to know of your communicate.h (as well as of any other Q_OBJECT'ed classes) to do its job. Unless you place them into .pro file under HEADERS section - you will get this "undefined reference"

Comment: I am using codeblocks in Windows 7. I cant find any .pro file with the project directory...can u be more specific please?

Comment: @Zeks yes you're right, Qt needs to know the custom header too

Comment: I've had troubles compling RedisQtAdapter from hiredis lib, as I was receiving linker errors. What actually helped - thanks to this answer - was adding e.g. /usr/local/include/hiredis/adapters/qt.h under HEADERS section in .pro file.

Comment: This is indeed quite unexpected for unexperienced qmake user. Especially after CMake which automatically figures out all required header files.

Comment: @AlexXoundOS I just found this in CMake with Qt.  Pure virtual base class header must be explicitly included.

Answer (score 24):

A quick option to solve the problem is to **remove the Q_OBJECT macro**, this will allow you to compile and test your application,
***but, not a right choice***, if you intend to work every day with QT on CB must configure your environment.

One option that I personally like more and create a custom makefile and a file. "pro" for the application it is easily transportable in other environments as "QtCreator" "NetBeansIDE", etc.

I'll quickly explain what are the steps to follow. If you have installed QtCreator deserves support of self-generated by QtCreator file, and with a little experience can build your own files.

*This example only allow you to compile and run the files under "Target Release" later you will have to customize your work environment*

- Create file: *Makefile*

```
####### Compiler, tools and options

PROJECT_NAME  = Communicate
QT_INCLUDE    = /usr/local/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/include/
QT_MKSPECS    = /usr/local/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/mkspecs/
QT_LIB        = /usr/local/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib
QT_QMAKE      = /usr/local/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/bin/
CC            = gcc
CXX           = g++
DEFINES       = -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED
CFLAGS        = -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I$(QT_MKSPECS)linux-g++ -I../$(PROJECT_NAME) -I$(QT_INCLUDE)QtCore -I$(QT_INCLUDE)QtGui -I/usr/local/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/include -I. -I../$(PROJECT_NAME) -I.
LINK          = g++
LFLAGS        = -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,$(QT_LIB)
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)  -L$(QT_LIB) -lQtGui -L$(QT_LIB) -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lQtCore -lpthread 
AR            = ar cqs
RANLIB        = 
QMAKE         = $(QT_QMAKE)qmake
TAR           = tar -cf
COMPRESS      = gzip -9f
COPY          = cp -f
SED           = sed
COPY_FILE     = $(COPY)
COPY_DIR      = $(COPY) -r
STRIP         = strip
INSTALL_FILE  = install -m 644 -p
INSTALL_DIR   = $(COPY_DIR)
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p

####### Output directory

OBJECTS_DIR   = ./Release

####### Files

SOURCES       = ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/main.cpp \
        ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/communicate.cpp moc_communicate.cpp
OBJECTS       = main.o \
        communicate.o \
        moc_communicate.o
DIST          = $(QT_MKSPECS)common/unix.conf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)common/linux.conf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)common/gcc-base.conf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)common/gcc-base-unix.conf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)common/g++-base.conf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)common/g++-unix.conf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)qconfig.pri \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)modules/qt_webkit_version.pri \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/qt_functions.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/qt_config.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/default_pre.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/release.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/default_post.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/unix/gdb_dwarf_index.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/warn_on.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/qt.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/unix/thread.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/moc.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/resources.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/uic.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/yacc.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/lex.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/include_source_dir.prf \
        ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/$(PROJECT_NAME).pro
QMAKE_TARGET  = $(PROJECT_NAME) Release
DESTDIR       = $(OBJECTS_DIR)
TARGET        = $(PROJECT_NAME)

first: all
####### Implicit rules

.SUFFIXES: .o .c .cpp .cc .cxx .C

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.cc.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.cxx.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.C.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

####### Build rules

all: Makefile $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):  $(OBJECTS)  
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(OBJCOMP) $(LIBS)

Makefile: ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/$(PROJECT_NAME).pro  $(QT_MKSPECS)linux-g++/qmake.conf $(QT_MKSPECS)common/unix.conf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)common/linux.conf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)common/gcc-base.conf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)common/gcc-base-unix.conf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)common/g++-base.conf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)common/g++-unix.conf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)qconfig.pri \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)modules/qt_webkit_version.pri \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/qt_functions.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/qt_config.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/default_pre.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/release.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/default_post.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/unix/gdb_dwarf_index.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/warn_on.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/qt.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/unix/thread.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/moc.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/resources.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/uic.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/yacc.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/lex.prf \
        $(QT_MKSPECS)features/include_source_dir.prf \
        $(QT_LIB)/libQtGui.prl \
        $(QT_LIB)/libQtCore.prl
    $(QMAKE) -spec $(QT_MKSPECS)linux-g++ -o Makefile ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/$(PROJECT_NAME).pro
$(QT_MKSPECS)common/unix.conf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)common/linux.conf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)common/gcc-base.conf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)common/gcc-base-unix.conf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)common/g++-base.conf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)common/g++-unix.conf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)qconfig.pri:
$(QT_MKSPECS)modules/qt_webkit_version.pri:
$(QT_MKSPECS)features/qt_functions.prf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)features/qt_config.prf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)features/exclusive_builds.prf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)features/default_pre.prf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)features/release.prf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)features/default_post.prf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)features/unix/gdb_dwarf_index.prf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)features/warn_on.prf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)features/qt.prf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)features/unix/thread.prf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)features/moc.prf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)features/resources.prf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)features/uic.prf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)features/yacc.prf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)features/lex.prf:
$(QT_MKSPECS)features/include_source_dir.prf:
$(QT_LIB)/libQtGui.prl:
$(QT_LIB)/libQtCore.prl:
qmake:  FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -spec $(QT_MKSPECS)linux-g++ -o Makefile ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/$(PROJECT_NAME).pro

dist: 
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) .tmp/$(PROJECT_NAME)1.0.0 || $(MKDIR) .tmp/$(PROJECT_NAME)1.0.0 
    $(COPY_FILE) --parents $(SOURCES) $(DIST) .tmp/$(PROJECT_NAME)1.0.0/ && $(COPY_FILE) --parents ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/communicate.h .tmp/$(PROJECT_NAME)1.0.0/ && $(COPY_FILE) --parents ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/main.cpp ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/communicate.cpp .tmp/$(PROJECT_NAME)1.0.0/ && (cd `dirname .tmp/$(PROJECT_NAME)1.0.0` && $(TAR) $(PROJECT_NAME)1.0.0.tar $(PROJECT_NAME)1.0.0 && $(COMPRESS) $(PROJECT_NAME)1.0.0.tar) && $(MOVE) `dirname .tmp/$(PROJECT_NAME)1.0.0`/$(PROJECT_NAME)1.0.0.tar.gz . && $(DEL_FILE) -r .tmp/$(PROJECT_NAME)1.0.0


clean:compiler_clean 
    -$(DEL_FILE) $(OBJECTS)
    -$(DEL_FILE) *~ core *.core


####### Sub-libraries

distclean: clean
    -$(DEL_FILE) $(TARGET) 

#-$(DEL_FILE) Makefile


check: first

mocclean: compiler_moc_header_clean compiler_moc_source_clean

mocables: compiler_moc_header_make_all compiler_moc_source_make_all

compiler_moc_header_make_all: moc_communicate.cpp
compiler_moc_header_clean:
    -$(DEL_FILE) moc_communicate.cpp
moc_communicate.cpp: ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/communicate.h
    $(QT_QMAKE)moc $(DEFINES) $(INCPATH) ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/communicate.h -o moc_communicate.cpp

compiler_rcc_make_all:
compiler_rcc_clean:
compiler_image_collection_make_all: qmake_image_collection.cpp
compiler_image_collection_clean:
    -$(DEL_FILE) qmake_image_collection.cpp
compiler_moc_source_make_all:
compiler_moc_source_clean:
compiler_uic_make_all:
compiler_uic_clean:
compiler_yacc_decl_make_all:
compiler_yacc_decl_clean:
compiler_yacc_impl_make_all:
compiler_yacc_impl_clean:
compiler_lex_make_all:
compiler_lex_clean:
compiler_clean: compiler_moc_header_clean 

####### Compile

main.o: ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/main.cpp ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/communicate.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o main.o ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/main.cpp

communicate.o: ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/communicate.cpp ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/communicate.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o communicate.o ../$(PROJECT_NAME)/communicate.cpp

moc_communicate.o: moc_communicate.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o moc_communicate.o moc_communicate.cpp

####### Install

install:   FORCE

uninstall:   FORCE

FORCE:
```

- Create Project file: *Communicate.pro*

```
QT       += core gui

TARGET = Communicate
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        communicate.cpp

HEADERS  += communicate.h
```

- Setup Custom Makefile  ...Project->properties:

[image: Setup Makefile]

- Setup Run Action ...Project->properties:

[image: Set run action]

- Run

[image: Run]

*Although that CB is an optimal environment for working with wxWidgets, and C/C++ in general, I personally think that in the case of working with Qt, QtCreator provides a development environment more native and optimized to work with your projects QT.*

Answer (score 6):

You need to define the destructor. Even though it derives from a QObject it's not enough for the compiler to use default constructor/destructors.

[Qt Linker Error: "undefined reference to vtable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555816/qt-object-linker-problem-undefined-reverence-to-vtable)