# qt - undefined reference to `_imp__Z*'

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Good day all

*Please note: C++ newbie here*

I am creating shared libraries among various other c++ features to allow for a complete understanding, however I am at a loss.

**Problem:**

As the title suggests, a list of errors:

I have no idea what causes them, and googling does not provide much insight either. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010922/qt-undefined-reference-to-vtable) to add the `Q_Object` macro, I have done so but obviously it is of no use.

Various other SO posts suggest checking the correct header, etc which is correct.

**Error:**

```
netm.cpp:3: error: undefined reference to `vtable for netm'
netm.cpp:3: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN4miscC1Ev'

netm.cpp:6: error: undefined reference to `vtable for netm'
netm.cpp:6: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN4miscC1Ev'
//...
```

*I have several more errors similar to these above, but solving these should assist me in resolving the rest*

From all the tutorials, etc I have followed, I have done nothing out of the ordinary.

**Note:** I am unsure what information is all required, if more is required, I'll gladly share.

**//.pro**

```
QT       -= gui
QT       += network

TARGET = netm
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += NETM_LIBRARY

SOURCES += netm.cpp

HEADERS += netm.h\
        netm_global.h

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

**//netm_global.h - FULL**

```
#ifndef NETM_GLOBAL_H
#define NETM_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(NETM_LIBRARY)
#  define NETMSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define NETMSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // NETM_GLOBAL_H
```

**//netm.h - FULL**

```
#ifndef NETM_H
#define NETM_H

#include "netm_global.h"
#include "../misc/misc.h"
#include "../gen/gen.h"

#include <QHostInfo>
#include <QTcpSocket>

class NETMSHARED_EXPORT netm
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    netm();
    netm(QString hostname);
    bool Send(int portNumber, char* message = NULL);
    ReturnObject read();

    bool isServerOnline(QString IP = QString());
    int getPing(QString IP = QString());
    void getIP();
    void disconnectFromServer();
    ~netm();

private slots:
    void getIP();

private:
    misc m;
    QHostInfo serverInfo;
    QHostAddress serverIP;
    QTcpSocket tcp_con;

};

#endif // NETM_H
```

**//netm.cpp - Partial**

```
#include "netm.h"

netm::netm(){                                    <--- ERROR line
}

netm::netm(QString hostname)                     <--- ERROR line
{
    serverInfo.lookupHost(hostname, 0, SLOT(getIP()));
}

//...
```

Help (with explanations) would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

As suggested, I defined the constructor in `misc.cpp`, since it was not present.

Recompiling, I read an error mentioning that the `netm` class needed to inherit from QObject.

Thus adding/changing:

**//netm.h - Partial**

```
#include //...
#include <QObject>

class NETMSHARED_EXPORT netm : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    netm();
    netm(QString hostname);
    //...
};
```

**Errors persist:**

```
netm.cpp:3: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN4miscC1Ev'
netm.cpp:3: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN4miscD1Ev'
netm.cpp:6: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN4miscC1Ev'
netm.cpp:6: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN4miscD1Ev'
```

For completeness sake (`misc` is also a dynamic library):

**//misc.h**

```
#ifndef MISC_H
#define MISC_H

#include "misc_global.h"

#include <QString>
#include <QList>


class MISCSHARED_EXPORT misc
{
public:

    misc();
    ~misc();

    //String Literals
    //Network related
    static QString googleDNS;

    //Command Codes
    static QString CMD_AUTH;
    static QString CMD_REQ;

    //Request Codes
    static QString REQ_USER_INFO;
    static QString REQ_VPN_DATA;
    static QString REQ_VPN_UP;

    //...
};
```

//misc.cpp

```
#include "misc.h"

misc::misc(){
    //Network related
    QString googleDNS = QStringLiteral("8.8.8.8");

    //Command Codes
    QString CMD_AUTH = QStringLiteral("AUTH");
    QString CMD_REQ = QStringLiteral("REQ");

    //Request Codes
    QString REQ_USER_INFO = QStringLiteral("USER_INFO");
    QString REQ_VPN_DATA = QStringLiteral("VPN_DATA");
    QString REQ_VPN_UP = QStringLiteral("VPN_UP");
}

misc::~misc(){}
```

As seen here, the constructor exists,

any other thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing calls to `_imp___ZN4miscC1Ev`, which is `misc::misc()` according to `c++filt`, likely means that the class `misc` is missing a defined default constructor. Check to make sure you're compiling in a definition for `misc::misc()`.

For the `vtable` error, make sure that you've provided a definition (even if empty or stubbed out) for every function declared in `netm` (or at minimum all of the virtual functions in `netm`). The `vtable` for a class references every virtual function, so all of the virtual functions must be defined or it will not compile.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response, I had the constructor declared, but not defined in the source. I proceeded to recompile and ran qmake again, see update, basically problem persists.

Comment: but `misc.cpp` isn't listed in your SOURCES list - is it actually being compiled at all?

Comment: so, to clarify, I need to add the `misc.cpp` to SOURCES; should I do the same for `misc.h` by adding it under HEADERS? I thought this "sort of done automaticlly" when using the #include "../path/to/misc.h"

Comment: Nope, including a file only includes that header, but won't automatically pull in related source files into the build. I find that the quickest way of verifying whether a file is actually being built or not is simply to introduce an error (a syntax error, #error or anything else) and see if the build breaks as expected.