# Migration from qmake to cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qmake

I have followed this guide http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstartedqt.html and everything works fine.
But now I want to convert this project from qmake to cmake; this is the CMakeLists.txt

```
project(Notepad)

# Application Version, managed by release script
set(APPLICATIONS_VERSION_MAJOR "0")
set(APPLICATIONS_VERSION_MINOR "0")
set(APPLICATIONS_VERSION_MICRO "1")
set(APPLICATIONS_VERSION "${APPLICATIONS_VERSION_MAJOR}.${APPLICATIONS_VERSION_MINOR}.${APPLICATIONS_VERSION_MICRO}")

# Minimum required software
set(CMAKE_MIN_REQUIRED_VERSION "3.7.2")
set(QT_MIN_REQUIRED_VERSION "5.7.1")
set(KF5_MIN_REQUIRED_VERSION "5.31.0")
set(ECM_MIN_REQUIRED_VERSION "5.31.0")

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION "${CMAKE_MIN_REQUIRED_VERSION}" FATAL_ERROR)

# Configure ECM
find_package(ECM "${ECM_MIN_REQUIRED_VERSION}" REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${ECM_MODULE_PATH})

include(FeatureSummary)
include(ECMSetupVersion)

# Generate header with version number
ecm_setup_version("${APPLICATIONS_VERSION}" VARIABLE_PREFIX NOTEPAD
                  VERSION_HEADER "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/notepad_version.h"
)

# Find Qt modules
find_package(Qt5 ${QT_MIN_VERSION} CONFIG REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    Core
    Gui
    Widgets
)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) # C++11...
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON) #...is required...
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF) #...without compiler extensions like gnu++11

set(notepad_SRCS main.cpp notepad.h notepad.cpp)

add_executable(notepad ${notepad_SRCS})

target_link_libraries(notepad
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Gui
)

feature_summary(WHAT ALL FATAL_ON_MISSING_REQUIRED_PACKAGES)
```

And I get this output:

```
/documenti/deglans/Programmazione/QtCreator/Notepad/build> make -j4
Scanning dependencies of target notepad_automoc
[ 25%] Automatic uic for target notepad
Generating ui header ui_notepad.h
[ 25%] Built target notepad_automoc
Scanning dependencies of target notepad
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/notepad.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/notepad.dir/notepad.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable notepad
CMakeFiles/notepad.dir/notepad.cpp.o: In function `Notepad::Notepad(QWidget*)':
/documenti/deglans/Programmazione/QtCreator/Notepad/notepad.cpp:28: undefined reference to `vtable for Notepad'
/documenti/deglans/Programmazione/QtCreator/Notepad/notepad.cpp:28: undefined reference to `vtable for Notepad'
CMakeFiles/notepad.dir/notepad.cpp.o: In function `Notepad::~Notepad()':
/documenti/deglans/Programmazione/QtCreator/Notepad/notepad.cpp:33: undefined reference to `vtable for Notepad'
/documenti/deglans/Programmazione/QtCreator/Notepad/notepad.cpp:33: undefined reference to `vtable for Notepad'
CMakeFiles/notepad.dir/notepad.cpp.o: In function `Notepad::tr(char const*, char const*, int)':
/documenti/deglans/Programmazione/QtCreator/Notepad/notepad.h:28: undefined reference to `Notepad::staticMetaObject'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/notepad.dir/build.make:123: recipe for target 'notepad' failed
make[2]: *** [notepad] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/notepad.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/notepad.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
*** Errore: Codice di uscita 2 ***
```

This is the part of code that give error when using cmake:

```
Notepad::Notepad(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Notepad)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Notepad::~Notepad()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Note that with qmake and QtCreator I have non problem, the problem born when I try to use KDevelop and cmake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt undefined reference to vtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010922/qt-undefined-reference-to-vtable)

Comment: No because the problem is only when I use cmake, but with qmake all works fine....

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but maybe an explicit `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)` is needed?

Comment: Yes the problem is `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)` thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved the problem by adding this line `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)` as suggested by Lorenz.
So CMakeLists.txt become:

```
project(Notepad)

# Application Version, managed by release script
set(APPLICATIONS_VERSION_MAJOR "0")
set(APPLICATIONS_VERSION_MINOR "0")
set(APPLICATIONS_VERSION_MICRO "1")
set(APPLICATIONS_VERSION "${APPLICATIONS_VERSION_MAJOR}.${APPLICATIONS_VERSION_MINOR}.${APPLICATIONS_VERSION_MICRO}")

# Minimum required software
set(CMAKE_MIN_REQUIRED_VERSION "3.7.2")
set(QT_MIN_REQUIRED_VERSION "5.7.1")
set(KF5_MIN_REQUIRED_VERSION "5.31.0")
set(ECM_MIN_REQUIRED_VERSION "5.31.0")

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION "${CMAKE_MIN_REQUIRED_VERSION}" FATAL_ERROR)

# Configure ECM
find_package(ECM "${ECM_MIN_REQUIRED_VERSION}" REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${ECM_MODULE_PATH})

include(FeatureSummary)
include(ECMSetupVersion)

# Generate header with version number
ecm_setup_version("${APPLICATIONS_VERSION}" VARIABLE_PREFIX NOTEPAD
              VERSION_HEADER "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/notepad_version.h"
)

# Find Qt modules
find_package(Qt5 ${QT_MIN_VERSION} CONFIG REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    Core
    Gui
    Widgets
)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON) # <<<<<<<-----------------------------

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) # C++11...
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON) #...is required...
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF) #...without compiler extensions like gnu++11

set(notepad_SRCS main.cpp notepad.h notepad.cpp)

add_executable(notepad ${notepad_SRCS})

target_link_libraries(notepad
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Gui
)

feature_summary(WHAT ALL FATAL_ON_MISSING_REQUIRED_PACKAGES)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the (full) solution.
You can also accept your own answer as the accepted answer/solution.