# qt - undefined reference to `vtable for myObj' in qt console application - signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qobject

I need to capture emited signals from a QProcess for testing purposes.

Since I am using a console application, I resolved to create a class in my main.cpp file called `myObj` using mainly [this example](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-33123.html):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QLoggingCategory>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QString>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>

class myObj : public QObject
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    myObj(QObject *parent = 0);
//    virtual ~Communicate();
    ~myObj();

public slots:
    void registerFinished(int signal);
    void registerAboutToClose();
    void registerChannelReadyRead(int signal);
    void registerReadChannelFinished();
    void registerReadyRead();
    void registerReadyReadStandardOutput();
    void registerStarted();
};

myObj::myObj(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)             <--- LINE 72 Error
{

}

//virtual myObj::~Communicate(){

//}

myObj::~myObj(){                  <--- LINE 81 Error

}

void myObj::registerFinished(int signal){
    qDebug() << "exit code = " << QString::number(signal);
}
void myObj::registerAboutToClose(){
    qDebug() << "aboutToClose";
}
void myObj::registerChannelReadyRead(int signal){
    qDebug() << "channelReadyRead = " << QString::number(signal);
}
void myObj::registerReadChannelFinished(){
    qDebug() << "readChannelFinished";
}
void myObj::registerReadyRead(){
    qDebug() << "exit code";
}
void myObj::registerReadyReadStandardOutput(){
    qDebug() << "exit code";
}
void myObj::registerStarted(){
    qDebug() << "started";
}

myObj *myO;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    myO = new myObj();

    //....
}
```

**Problem:**

> main.cpp:72: error: undefined reference to `vtable for myObj'
>
> main.cpp:81: error: undefined reference to `vtable for myObj'

I have looked at a number of SO pages e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010922/qt-undefined-reference-to-vtable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205877/qt-undefined-reference-to-vtable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552069/undefined-reference-to-vtable-trying-to-compile-a-qt-project) and various others, yet had not found a solution

**I have tried/done:**

- added the Q_Object Macro
- ran qmake
- rebuilt
- checked the #include

**.pro file**

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = serv_app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: See if this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065154/undefined-reference-to-vtable

Comment: remove Q_OBJECT

Comment: @eyllanesc removing the Q_OBJECT Macro will remove the class's ability to utilise features like signals and slots -> http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Comment: If you separate the code from the class into another file, it does not generate that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

- @eyllanesc solution works for sure.
- add the line `#include "main.moc"` before or after you `main()` function.

When you put the class into its own header file, `qmake` will generate the proper `moc` file.

But when you put the class into a `.cpp` file, the `moc` code is not generated unless you put the line I said before.

**Update #1**

In the [Qt tutorial about writing a Unit Test](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qttestlib-tutorial1-example.html#writing-a-test) we can find the following info:

> Note that if both the declaration and the implementation of our test
>   class are in a .cpp file, we also need to include the generated moc
>   file to make Qt's introspection work.

So this is another example where we need to include the `moc` file.

Comment: had to put the `#include "main.moc"` just above the main method, also "main.moc" was not found when first placed. After building, this message went away.

Comment: Yep. You need to clean your build directory or rerun qmake.

Comment: In my profile you have a link to my homepage. Contact me. But I think it is also a good idea to post a question in SO.

Comment: If you are interested in taking a look, it would be very very very much appreciated! -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41848939/reading-and-writing-to-qprocess-in-qt-console-application