# How to exit a "game" in Qt when health is 0

Tags: qt, 2d, exit, qapplication

I'm quite new to Qt, but I got into it to start experimenting with making 2D games. I've got a extremely rough and simple game started, but I have an issue. Whenever the health gets to 0, the game doesn't end. I just want to know how to end the game and where to put this exit command before making a "Game Over" screen. My code is below, and from what I can grasp, I assume the QApplication::quit() goes in the Game.cpp file. Doing this by taking the health integer from Health.cpp and Health.h and putting it in Game.cpp. Any help is appreciated. Here is the code I feel the answers lie in, if more info is needed, ask.

**Game.h**

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Score.h"
#include "Health.h"
#include "Level.h"
#include "Main.h"

class Game: public QGraphicsView{
public:
    Game(QWidget * parent=0);

    QGraphicsScene * scene;
    Player * player;
    Score * score;
    Health * health;
    Level * level;
    Main * close;
    int end();
};

#endif // GAME_H
```

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h" 
#include <QTimer>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>
#include <QFont>
#include "Enemy.h"
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QImage>
#include <QApplication>

Game::Game(QWidget *parent){
    // create the scene
    scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    scene->setSceneRect(0,0,800,600); // make the scene 800x600        instead of infinity by infinity (default)
    setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QImage(":/images/bg.png")));

    // make the newly created scene the scene to visualize (since Game is a QGraphicsView Widget,
    // it can be used to visualize scenes)
    setScene(scene);
    setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setFixedSize(800,600);

    // create the player
    player = new Player();
    player->setPos(400,500); // TODO generalize to always be in the     middle bottom of screen
    // make the player focusable and set it to be the current focus
    player->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
    player->setFocus();
    // add the player to the scene
    scene->addItem(player);

    // create the score/health
    score = new Score();
    scene->addItem(score);
    health = new Health();
    health->setPos(health->x(),health->y()+25);
    scene->addItem(health);
    level = new Level();
    scene->addItem(level);Bull
    level->setPos(level->x(),level->y()+50);

    // spawn enemies
    QTimer * timer = new QTimer();
    QObject::connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),player,SLOT(spawn()));
    timer->start(2000);

    // play background music
    QMediaPlayer * music = new QMediaPlayer();
    music->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/bgsound.mp3"));
    music->play();

    show();
}

int Game::end(){
    if (health == 0){
        QApplication::quit();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Health.h**

```
#ifndef HEALTH_H
#define HEALTH_H

#include <QGraphicsTextItem>

class Health: public QGraphicsTextItem{
public:
    Health(QGraphicsItem * parent=0);
    void decrease();
    int getHealth();
private:
    int health;
};

#endif // HEALTH_H
```

**Health.cpp**

```
#include "Health.h"
#include <QFont>
#include <QApplication>

Health::Health(QGraphicsItem *parent): QGraphicsTextItem(parent){
    // initialize the score to 0
    health = 3;

    // draw the text
    setPlainText(QString("Health: ") + QString::number(health)); //   Health: 3
    setDefaultTextColor(Qt::red);
    setFont(QFont("times",16));
}

void Health::decrease(){
    health--;
    setPlainText(QString("Health: ") + QString::number(health)); //     Health: 2
}

int Health::getHealth(){
    return health;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "Game.h"
#include "Main.h"

Game * game;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    game = new Game();
    game->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `end()` function is never called.

The best way to achieve what you want to is to use [Qt's signal/slot mechanism](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html). It amkes it easy to connect an event (signal) to an action (slot):

- Add `Q_OBJECT` macro to `Health` and `Game` classes and make sure your compilation environment [moc's](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html) the two header files
- Declare in `Health` a `signal` named `dead()`
- Emit the signal from `Health::decrease()`
- Make `Game::end()` be a `slot` and be `void`
- Connect `Health::dead()` to `Game::end()`

Then, `Game::end()` will be called as soon as `Health` reaches zero.

```
class Health: public QGraphicsTextItem 
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Health(QGraphicsItem * parent=0);
    void decrease();
    int getHealth();
signals:
    void dead();
private:
    int health;
};

...

class Game: public QGraphicsView{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ...

public slots:
    void end();
};

...

void Health::decrease(){
    health--;
    setPlainText(QString("Health: ") + QString::number(health));
    if ( health == 0 )
        emit dead();
}

...

Game::Game(QWidget *parent){

    ...

    connect( health, SIGNAL(dead()), this, SLOT(end()) );

}

...

void Game::end(){
    // no need to test health anymore, as signal is emited when health is zero
    // do some extra stuff before exiting
    QApplication::quit();
}
```

If `end()` only calls `QApplication::quit()`, you can remove it and diectly connect the signal to `QApplication::quit()`, like that:

```
connect( health, SIGNAL(dead()), qApp, SLOT(quit()) );
```

Also note that you were testing `health == 0` in `Game::end()`, but `health` is a pointer, and, looking at your code, it will never be `0` (you maybe meant to write `if ( health->getHealth() == 0 )`.

Comment: Did everything you said, but when I compile I get the error "undefined reference to Health::dead()" and points to the lines `if (health==0)` `emit dead();`. What's wrong now?

Comment: Did you moc Health.h?

Comment: I did not, but when I added Q_OBJECT to Health.h I now get MORE errors while compiling, adding  "undefined reference to vtable for Health" in the function Health::decrease and Health.cpp, while still having the "undefined reference" error. Frustration is setting in >.>

Comment: If you're writting code based on Qt, you'll have to deal with that moc stuff. You need to have any header file with a Q_OBJECT macro be moced (it's a compilation step specific to Qt, see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html). QtCreator does it for you and there could be a plugin for your IDE if you're not using QtCreator (there's a Visual Studio plugin and also some CMake macros if using CMake). If you can't make Q_OBJECT work, you can't use signa/slots, then you can't use Qt...

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555816/qt-linker-error-undefined-reference-to-vtable.

Answer (score 0):

In `Health::decrease` emit a signal or put the logic for it in where the "player is shot" area.  <strike>But to do that, you to `Health` or the class with the logic to be a `QObject` so that it gets the signals and slots in the header.</strike> EDIT `QGraphicsTextItem` is already a `QObject`. See comments.

Connect the signal to the view's `close()` right after the Health class or Player class is instantiated.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: `Health` is already a `QObject` (derives from `QGraphicsTextItem`)

Comment: You are right; thanks for keeping me honest.  I hadn't looked at the docs for it lately.  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsobject.html  However, most stock QGraphicsItems are not `QGraphicsObjects`. Only `QGraphicsSvgItem, QGraphicsTextItem, QGraphicsVideoItem,' and 'QGraphicsWidget` are QObjects.

Comment: Also this seems a great place to use a `Q_PROPERTY`.  You can get all your setters and getters and signals and slots and everything very quickly if you right click and use `Refactor...` in Qt Creator.