# Error connecting Worker Thread signal with MainWindow slot (Qt5)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qthread, vtable

I want to write a simple Application which launches a thread to do some computations. The worker thread should periodically send signals to the MainWindow to inform it about the current state of progress. In order to implement the worker thread, I subclass `QThread` and reimplement the `run` method. When I compile the program using QTCreator, I always get these two errors:

In the Header file of `Worker`, which implements the working thread:

```
.../worker.h:7: error: undefined reference to `vtable for Worker'
```

In the Source file of `MainWindow`, when I try to connect the `Worker` signal to the `MainWindow` slot:

```
.../worker.cpp:23: error: undefined reference to `Worker::updateLabelSig(int)'
```

**Worker.h**

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QThread>
#include <vector>

class Worker : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

    void run() override;
private:
    void computeNumbers();
    std::vector<int> foundNumbers;
    int upperLimit;
signals:
    void updateLabelSig(int);
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

**Worker.cpp**

```
#include "worker.h"

void Worker::run(){
    exec();
    computeNumbers();
}

void Worker::computeNumbers(){
    upperLimit=1e5;
    foundNumbers.push_back(1);
    for(int i=2; i<upperLimit; i++){
/////////////do some calculations and emit regular signals to inform main window///////////////////
        if(i%10000==0)
            emit updateLabelSig(i);
    }
}
```

In the MainWindow class, I have a button which should launch the thread if clicked:

**MainWindow.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include "worker.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_mainbutton_clicked()
{
    Worker* w=new Worker;
    QObject::connect(w,SIGNAL(Worker::updateLabelSig(int)),this,SLOT(updateLabel(int)));
    w->start();
}

void MainWindow::updateLabel(int i){
    findChild<QLabel*>("mainlabel")->setText(QString("Numbers searched so far: ")+QString::number(i));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt Linker Error: "undefined reference to vtable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555816/qt-linker-error-undefined-reference-to-vtable)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turned out that I simply needed to rerun `qmake` in order to get things to work. When I first wrote the header file `worker.h` I forgot to add the `Q_OBJECT` macro which I added later. However, I didn't run `qmake`.