# QtRemoteObjects autogenerated replica header complaining about undefined vtable

Tags: qt, qt5, qtremoteobjects

Started using QtRO and generated files inherently complain about vtable:

```
#ifndef REP_REMOTEEXAMPLE_H
#define REP_REMOTEEXAMPLE_H

// This is an autogenerated file.
// Do not edit this file, any changes made will be lost the next time it is generated.

#include <QtCore/qobject.h>
#include <QtCore/qdatastream.h>
#include <QtCore/qvariant.h>
#include <QtCore/qmetatype.h>

#include <QtRemoteObjects/qremoteobjectnode.h>
#include <QtRemoteObjects/qremoteobjectpendingcall.h>
#include <QtRemoteObjects/qremoteobjectreplica.h>


class remoteExampleReplica : public QRemoteObjectReplica
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_CLASSINFO(QCLASSINFO_REMOTEOBJECT_TYPE, "remoteExample")
    Q_CLASSINFO(QCLASSINFO_REMOTEOBJECT_SIGNATURE, "5e40a606abdd95f709878d419edaa735fce25d0d")

public:
    remoteExampleReplica() : QRemoteObjectReplica() { initialize(); }
    static void registerMetatypes()
    {
        static bool initialized = false;
        if (initialized)
            return;
        initialized = true;
    }

private:
    remoteExampleReplica(QRemoteObjectNode *node, const QString &name = QString())
        : QRemoteObjectReplica(ConstructWithNode)
    {
        initializeNode(node, name);
    }

    void initialize() override
    {
        remoteExampleReplica::registerMetatypes();
        QVariantList properties;
        properties.reserve(0);
        setProperties(properties);
    }

public:
    virtual ~remoteExampleReplica() {}


Q_SIGNALS:
    void Close(QString a);
    void Open(QString b);

public Q_SLOTS:
    void onClosed()
    {
        static int __repc_index = remoteExampleReplica::staticMetaObject.indexOfSlot("onClosed()");
        QVariantList __repc_args;
        send(QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, __repc_index, __repc_args);
    }
    void onOpened()
    {
        static int __repc_index = remoteExampleReplica::staticMetaObject.indexOfSlot("onOpened()");
        QVariantList __repc_args;
        send(QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, __repc_index, __repc_args);
    }

private:
    friend class QT_PREPEND_NAMESPACE(QRemoteObjectNode);
};

#if (QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 5, 0))
#endif


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
QT_END_NAMESPACE


#endif // REP_REMOTEEXAMPLE_H
```

The issue points to the private constructor. I only included the replica header in my code without really using the remote object as a test run. I've read a lot about vtables how they work and when the linker complains about the vtable but in this case, with the private constructor, I'm not sure what the issue is. 
 Am I missing an implementation of the remote object? Did I not generate the files correctly?

.rep:

```
class remoteExample
{
  SIGNAL(Close(QString a));
  SIGNAL(Open(QString b));
  SLOT(onClosed());
  SLOT(onOpened());
};
```

Comment: Run qmake again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555816/qt-linker-error-undefined-reference-to-vtable

Comment: This was generated using `repc -i rep file.rep -o replica rep_file.h` command. Then the header was included in `main.cpp` but not used. It wasn't autogenerated.

Comment: oh wait, do I need to run `moc` on the generated .h file? since it includes `Q_OBJECT`, i'll give that a try