# Qt - Right Way to Implement Custom Signals and Slots

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slots

I have one MainWindow and one Class; I want to send data between them using custom signal and slot. I can't seem to figure it out, I need help.

Here is my code:
MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <iostream>
#include "receive.h"
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
signals:
    void sendit(QString name);
private slots:
    void on_send_button_clicked();
    void display(QString e)
    {        
     std::cout<<"Here is where I am called this "<<e.toStdString()<<std::endl;
    }

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "receive.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);    
   Receive *r = new Receive();
   connect(this, SIGNAL(sendit(QString)), r, SLOT(display(QString)));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_send_button_clicked()
{
    emit sendit(ui->lineEdit->text());

}
```

receive.h

```
#ifndef RECEIVE_H
#define RECEIVE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <QDialog>

class Receive : public QDialog
{
public:
    Receive();
private slots:
    void display(QString e);
};

#endif // RECEIVE_H
```

receive.cpp

```
#include "receive.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

Receive::Receive()
{

}

void Receive::display(QString e)
{    
 std::cout<<"Here is where I am called this "<<e.toStdString()<<std::endl;
}
```

When I run this program, I get this message:

06:26:29: Starting C:\Users\Troy\Documents\build-tests-Desktop_Qt_5_14_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug\tests.exe ...
QObject::connect: No such slot QDialog::display(QString) in ..\tests\mainwindow.cpp:11
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'MainWindow')

How do I get this done, please?

Thank  you for your help.

Comment: `Receive` is missing the Q_OBJECT macro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your slot in `Receive` needs to be public not private. Much the same as other class members, private slots can only be used by the class itself.

If you use the modern connect syntax you'll get a better compile time error:

```
connect(this, &MainWindow::sendit, r, &Receive::display);
```

You also need to make sure you add `Q_OBJECT` to every Qt class, it is missing from `Receive`.

Comment: Thank you. I did and I got this error: Undefined reference to 'vtable for Receive'

Comment: You might need to re-run qmake, also make sure you have implemented all methods in the class that you've declared: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555816/qt-linker-error-undefined-reference-to-vtable

Comment: Quick question please, is it possible to have this connection without having a pointer to Receive class?

Comment: Nope, you need an object to call a class method whether that's through a signal or any other means (signals and slots are essentially just glorified function pointers) however using the new connect syntax you can attach whatever you like to a signal, could be a static method or even a lambda in which cases you don't need an object to target