# qt error: undefined reference to `vtable for Thread'

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QThread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <QApplication>


using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

class Thread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Thread();
    ~Thread();
    void setMessage(const QString &_message);
    void stop();
protected:
    void run();
private:
    QString message;
    volatile bool stopped;
};

Thread::Thread()
{
    stopped = false;    
    run();
}

Thread::~Thread()
{

}


void Thread::run()
{
    while(!stopped){
        cerr << qPrintable(message);
        sleep(1);
    }
        stopped = false;
        cerr << endl;
}

void Thread::stop()
{
    stopped = true; 
}

void Thread::setMessage(const QString &_message)
{
    message = _message; 
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Thread *A,*B;
    A = new Thread();
    B = new Thread();
    A->setMessage("Thread A\n");
    B->setMessage("Thread B\n");
//.run();
//.run();
    sleep(10);
    A->stop();
    B->stop();
    return 0;
}
```

and i have error

```
g++ -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-O1 -o tmp main.o    -L/usr/lib -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread 
main.o: In function `Thread::~Thread()':
main.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `vtable for Thread'
main.o: In function `Thread::Thread()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1da): undefined reference to `vtable for Thread'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tmp] Error 1
```

Comment: Duplicate to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095298/gcc-c-linker-errors-undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-xxx-undefined-referen

Comment: @littleadv: that question doesn't really speak to the specific problem that needs to be addressed in the Qt Framework build environment being used here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to vtable. Trying to compile a Qt project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552069/undefined-reference-to-vtable-trying-to-compile-a-qt-project)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must generate a header with moc. This can be done automatically with the Qt build system. Instead of using gcc directly, you should use a qmake file.

Also you should probably separate the declaration and code into header file and cpp file.

Here is a description of what moc does: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/moc.html

And a similar question (with answers) here on stackoverflow:
[Undefined reference to vtable. Trying to compile a Qt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552069/undefined-reference-to-vtable-trying-to-compile-a-qt-project)

Answer (score 7):

You need to have a line at the bottom of your source file:

```
#include "main.moc"
```

That's because the declaration of `class Thread` isn't in a header - it's in a .cpp file. So by default `moc` won't run on it.  Adding the line does two things:

- it signals to `qmake` and `moc` that `moc` has to process the .cpp file
- it causes the stuff that `moc` generates to be pulled in by the compile step

So after adding that line you'll need to rerun `qmake` so it can update the makefiles to cause `main.moc` to be generated.

Normally, `moc` runs against header files and creates .cpp files that get included in the build (`qmake` sees to this).  This 'trick' causes `moc` to also be run on the .cpp filein question (and to have the `moc` generated code compiled in).

An alternative to including `main.moc` at the end of `main.cpp` is to move the definition of `class Thread` to a .h header file and `#include` that.  If the definition is in a header `qmake` and `moc` should handle things automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that the qmake system requires that your header file include  directly.  Mine was failing to generate a moc until I added that include.

Answer (score -1):

Simple add string to .pro file. This was helping for me in same problem

```
INSTALLS += target
```

See queudcustomtype example.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.